# Terraform: Unable to list all tagged and untagged resources from AWS

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to list all tagged and untagged aws resources using below terraform code :

main.tf

```
data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "tagged_resources" {
  tag_filter {
    key    = "*"
    values = ["*"]
  }
}

data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "untagged_resources" {
  tag_filter {
    key    = " "
    values = [" "]
  }
}

resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
  count = length(data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources.id) + length(data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.untagged_resources.id)

  triggers_replace =  {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = <<-EOT
       echo "Resource ID for tagged resources : ${element(data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources[*].id,count.index)} and Resource ID for untagged resources : ${element(data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.untagged_resources[*].id,count.index)}"
       
     EOT
  }
}

output "tagged_resources_ids" {
  value = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources[*].id
}
```

erraform apply output is as follows:

```
data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.untagged_resources: Reading...
data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources: Reading...
data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources: Read complete after 1s [id=aws]
data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.untagged_resources: Read complete after 1s [id=aws]

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # terraform_data.print_resources[0] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # terraform_data.print_resources[1] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # terraform_data.print_resources[2] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # terraform_data.print_resources[3] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # terraform_data.print_resources[4] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # terraform_data.print_resources[5] will be created
  + resource "terraform_data" "print_resources" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + triggers_replace = {
          + always_run = (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 6 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  ~ tagged_resources_ids = [
      - [],
      + "aws",
    ]
terraform_data.print_resources[5]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[0]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[5]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[5] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[0]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[0] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[1]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[1]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[1] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[5] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[2]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[2]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[2] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[4]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[4]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[4] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[3]: Creating...
terraform_data.print_resources[3]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
terraform_data.print_resources[3] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo \"Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws\"\n       \n"]
terraform_data.print_resources[5]: Creation complete after 0s [id=d71ba741-20a2-b2ac-4d55-0513f2a678e1]
terraform_data.print_resources[1] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[1]: Creation complete after 0s [id=d835d78f-93a9-870c-97ed-82daac1f46b7]
terraform_data.print_resources[2] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[2]: Creation complete after 0s [id=f0227bc6-9c3c-d3c0-5986-efeaa0446fcc]
terraform_data.print_resources[4] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[4]: Creation complete after 0s [id=629c2a01-7217-9aad-f4fb-05c663429d8c]
terraform_data.print_resources[0] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[0]: Creation complete after 0s [id=cdb59780-41fe-e427-a536-cf67bfd9cf97]
terraform_data.print_resources[3] (local-exec): Resource ID for tagged resources : aws and Resource ID for untagged resources : aws
terraform_data.print_resources[3]: Creation complete after 0s [id=0beb1fb7-a34a-aae0-85ab-91bb659a318c]

Apply complete! Resources: 6 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Outputs:

```
tagged_resources_ids = [
  "aws",
]
```

terraform_version: 1.4.6
hashicorp/aws v5.40.0

**Problem **
both echo statement and output variable shows id as "aws" in the output for both tagged and untagged resources instead of unique id.

Comment: Are you using the `count` meta-argument in any of the data sources?

Comment: count meta-argument is not used in any of the data sources ,but is used in resource block

Comment: But your data sources do not use `count` and you're trying to use the splat expression: `data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources[*]`.

Comment: then is it ok to use count in resource block (which I've tried above) to store length of tagged & untagged resources and use that count value to get the id of that particular resource (provisioner block). Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code to fetch tagged and untagged aws resources using terraform:

```
data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "tagged_resources" {
}


output "tagged_resources_list" {
  value = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources.resource_tag_mapping_list[*].resource_arn
}

output "resources_list_with_tag" {
  value = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.tagged_resources.resource_tag_mapping_list[*].tags

}
```

hope this helps someone.